# Keep line labels within plot visible when zooming

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I am using matplotlibs plt.axvline to plot vertical lines on a graph. I want to put labels on the vertical lines straight onto the graph, NOT in a legend.

I want my graph to have labels on the vertical lines that look like this:

[image: like this]

If I zoom in on a certain section, I would like the vertical line labels to move accordingly so they're still visible on screen. Like this:

[image: Like this]

Can anyone help me with this? It would be much appreciated!

My code so far is below:

```
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.utils.data import download_file
from astropy.table import Table
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class Spectrum:
    # Let's download the data to plot    
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url
        self.hdu_list = fits.open(download_file(url, cache=True), memmap=False)

    # Now lets plot the data
    def plot_spectra(self):
        x = np.array(Table(self.hdu_list[1].data).columns[1])
        x = 10 ** x
        y = np.array(Table(self.hdu_list[1].data).columns[0])
        plt.plot(x, y, 'k', lw=1)

    # Now lets plot the vertical lines, AND THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO ADD LABELS.
    def plot_spectral_types(self):
        my_type = input("Please enter the spectral type to plot (o, b, a, or f): ")
        if my_type is 'o':
            my_type = o_type
        elif my_type is 'b':
            my_type = b_type
        elif my_type is 'a':
            my_type = a_type
        elif my_type is 'f':
            my_type = f_type

        element, wavelength = zip(*my_type)
# Each vertical line's x value is a wavelength. 
# I want the vertical line's label to be the corresponding element.
        for i in wavelength:
            plt.axvline(linewidth=0.25, color='r', x=i)

o_type = [
('NIII', 4097),
('SiIV', 4089),
('H', 4340.5),
('HeI', 4471),
('HeII', 4541),
('NIII', 4632),
('NIII', 4640),
('CIII', 4650),
('HeII', 4686)
]

b_type = [
('SiIV', 4089),
('H', 4101.7),
('HeI', 4121),
('SiII', 4128),
('SiII', 4131),
('H', 4340.5),
('HeI', 4471),
('CIII', 4540),
('HeII', 4541),
('CIII', 4650),
('H', 4861.33)
]

a_type = [
('CaII (K)', 3933.70),
('CaII', 3968.50),
('H', 3970.10),
('H', 4101.70),
('HeI', 4121.00),
('SiII', 4128.00),
('SiII', 4131.00),
('FeI', 4299.00),
('FeI', 4303.00),
('TiII', 4303.00),
('H', 4340.50),
('MgII', 4481.00),
('H', 4861.30),
('H', 6562.70)
]

f_type = [
('CaII', 3933.70),
('CaII', 3968.50),
('H', 3970.10),
('H', 4101.70),
('HeI', 4121.00),
('SiII', 4128.00),
('SiII', 4131.00),
('CaI', 4227.00),
('FeI', 4299.00),
('FeI', 4303.00),
('H', 4340.50),
('CH', 4314.00),
('MgII', 4481.00),
('H', 4861.30),
('H', 6562.70)
]
```

Comment: I'd change the title of this to be more helpful to the next seeker -- "Keep labels within plot visible when zooming", maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text labels are in [data-coordinates](https://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html?highlight=transformations) by default, which is probably the issue you're having. You can transform the y-value to figure coordinates, that are relative to the current axis as it zooms, and leave the x-coordinate in data coordinates. A more freestanding (see MCVE) example:

```
from numpy.random import uniform
from math import sin, pi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms



fig, ax = plt.subplots()

transDA = transforms.blended_transform_factory(
    ax.transData, ax.transAxes) #  from the transforms tutorial

spectrum = uniform(0,1, 1000) + map(lambda x: sin(2*pi*x/800), range(1000)) #dummy data

ax.plot(range(4000,5000,1), spectrum )

o_type = [
('NIII', 4097),
('SiIV', 4089),
('H', 4340.5),
('HeI', 4471),
('HeII', 4541),
('NIII', 4632),
('NIII', 4640),
('CIII', 4650),
('HeII', 4686)
]

for wavelength in o_type:
        print(wavelength[0],wavelength[1])
        plt.axvline(linewidth=0.25, color='r', x=wavelength[1])
        plt.text(wavelength[1], # x-value from data
                 uniform(0,1), # wiggle the labels 2so they don't overlap
                 wavelength[0], # string label
                 transform = transDA,
                 color='red',
                 family='serif') # the III looked better serif.
```

Original plot. Note that the first two labels are respectively about halfway up the figure and maybe a quarter way up the picture: 
[image]
Zooming in, those labels have moved properly with the zoomed x-axis, but are still about halfway up the figure and a quarter up the figure: 
[image]